# C-Visit-Business visa issued post 24 April 2015

Tags: visas, uk

I applied for a 2 year Business visa in July 2015. From other answers I have read, it seems a Standard Visitor visa should have been issued given this category was removed post 24 April 2015.

But for some reason the visa that was issued was a C - Visit - Business category still, in July 2015, for a 2 year validity.

1. Any idea why this may have been?
2. Was it because the visa has a validity of 2 years? Note that the maximum stay is still limited to 6 months per visit (180 days)
3. Can I use this visa to travel to UK for a tourism / vacation trip with no business purpose in that trip at all?

Comment: Maybe they wanted to use up the existing C-Visit-Business stickers.  It makes no difference; after 24 April 2015, a C-Visit-Business visa is legally equivalent to the new standard visitor visa.  So yes, you can use the visa for tourism.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry if this looks a duplicate but I did go through all the other threads but could not figure why I had a C-Visit-Business stamp despite applying post the 24 April 2015 pivot date. And hence was worried that the rules could be different in my case. Is there any documentation which would cover my specific case on the home office website, which I could print and take with me just in case?

Comment: Good point.  I've retracted my close vote.  The question "why was I issued a C-Visit-Business visa after 24 Apr 2015" is not really a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks and too add for clarity, given that was the stamp that was given despite being post 24 April 2015, just wanted to make sure that the ability to visit for tourism purpose still apply and I can use that option for a vacation visit despite that and there is no technical point in the new rules which will make my case inadmissible?

Comment: That is covered in the linked question.

Comment: The vignettes are expensive! Posts were instructed to deplete existing stocks before reordering.  You can use it for tourism or business visits etc etc

Comment: Thank you all! The linked question I presume, Michael, you mean the one phoog marked as duplicate for initially, as that comment is now gone. But I do remember going through the links in that one before posting, it had links to the home office websites including the change document published there, though that document is virtually unreadable!